# rendering jquery grid on button click asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, jqgrid

I m having a page with two date fields and a dropdown... based on the values selected from those fields i have to call a server method which fetches the data and then bind the grid.. how is this possible using jquery grid... currently i know that i can call $("#list").jqGrid({}); on a button click which is inside a function... but the problem is that i want to pass  additional parameters also...

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $('#someButton').click(function() {
        // when the button is clicked 
        // send an AJAX call to the server to fetch data:
        $.ajax({
            url: '/home/someaction',
            data: { 
                // Use the data hash to send values to the server action
                date1: $('#date1').val(), 
                date2: $('#date2').val(), 
                ddlValue: $('#ddl').val() 
            },
            success: function(result) {
                //TODO: setup jqGrid here based on the results
                // returned from the server action
            }
        });
    });
});
```